# MongoDB $sort (aggregation) doesn't working

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation

I have this aggregation query:

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate([

{
    $facet: {
        "myAttrName": [
            {
                $match: {
                    $or: [
                        {
                            "key1": "value1"
                        },
                        {
                            "key2": "value2"
                        }
                    ],
                    status: "OK"
                }
            },
            {
                $skip: 0
            },
            {
                $limit: 10
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    timestamp: -1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}



])
```

Well.. it doesn't sorts the results properly. I just see them ordered by time of adding them "fifo".

When Im just doing regular find (*no aggregation*) with `.sort({timestamp: -1})` it works properly.

What am I missing in here?

Comment: move `$sort` stage to before `$skip` stage.

Comment: It sorts here https://mongoplayground.net/p/c8dCUoD-C0_ and yes, skip before sort makes little sense.

Comment: Please write this as an answer I will mark it correct.

Comment: @AlexBlex maybe the link you have provided handles this behind the scenes

Comment: It's a particularity of the `$facet`. In a "classic" pipeline it would have worked well https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/

Comment: @AlexisG, there is nothing special about `$facet`. The optimisations you are referring to are for   "$sort **precedes** a $limit" and "$sort **followed by** a $skip". Order matters. My playground example has exactly the same query with $facet as OP has posted. The reason why it works there is because there are only 2 elements in the test collection, both fit within the $limit. It applies $limit to documents in natural order, then sorts the result. Please read turivishal's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregation stages executing in order, in your query `$skip` and `$limit` stages executed before the `$sort`, so sort will apply only in 10 documents,

You can move `$sort` state before `$skip` stage.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-bovYhBfJmr)